# IOS: portrait window with navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, splash-screen

In my app I want to add a splash view from my firstViewController and I do this in viewDidLoad:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    splashImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"]];

    splashImageView.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;

    [appDelegate.window addSubview:splashImageView];
    splashImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);
```

it add well my splash but I have a portrait orientation window, I'm using storyboard and I start it with a navigation controller, what's the way to set this navigation in landscape to have a window in landscape? thanks